# Gradle not able to find dependencies when use build script named anything other than "build.gradle"

Tags: android, build, gradle

Gradle noobie, a little confused. I'm trying to tell gradle to use a different build script, from the command-line, but whenever I do so, it tells me it can't find my dependencies.

Whenever I call:

```
gradle -b build.gradle
```

It works fined.

But when I call:

```
gradle -b other.gradle
```

It pukes trying to find my dependencies. e.g.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project '<main_app>'.
> Project with path ':facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1:facebook' could not be found in root project '<main_app>'.
```

I'm using the exact same build script in the exact same directory, just named differently. Here it is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1:facebook')
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

My settings.gradle file:

```
include '<app_module>'
include '<:facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1:facebook>'
```

Comment: Do you have a root build.gradle? Could you show it to us?

Comment: Hey Vincent, no root build.gradle, but a settings.gradle which I've included above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-b` only works for single-project builds. In multi-project builds, `settings.gradle` determines which build scripts constitute the build, which project they belong to, and where they are located.

Comment: Thanks Peter, in settings.gradle, how can I specify which build scripts to use? As far as I can tell, I can point settings.gradle at different gradle projects, but within each project it will just pick up the default build.gradle. Is there any way to tell it to pick up a different build script than build.gradle?

Comment: It's fully configurable, e.g. `rootProject.buildFileName = "foo.gradle"`, or `project(":foo").buildFileName = "foo.gradle"`.